# Using hashing to create a PRNG with seed

Tags: c#, beginner, hashcode

So I wanted to code a simple PRNG for generating terrain in a game. It has to have the following properties:

1. Computationally cheap
2. Generate semi random numbers between 0 and an positive integer.
3. I need to be able to go back and teleport anywhere in the world so random.Next doesn't cut it.
4. I basically want a noise function. One output for each input with repeatable results.
5. No seed will be used. If I need another series I'll just shift x value by a couple of millions

These are some outputs produced by my program:

1 as input (x) gives 2 as a pseudo random number

2 as input (x) gives 2 as a pseudo random number

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Hashing_Functions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i0 = 0;


            while (true)
            {
                i0++;                
                Console.WriteLine(RandomHashFunction(i0, 10));
                //returns random number between 0 and max based on input
            }
        }

        static int RandomHashFunction(int input, int max)
        {
            var SHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string hash2string;
            double output;
            byte[] hash;
            SHA1.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input.ToString()));
            hash = SHA1.Hash;
            sb.Clear();

            foreach (byte b in hash)
            {
                sb.Append(b.ToString());
            }
            hash2string = sb.ToString();
            output = hash2string.GetHashCode();
            output = Math.IEEERemainder(output, max);
            output = Math.Abs(output);

            return Convert.ToInt16(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit but kept the context edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Most random number generators have ways of skipping forward and backward within their streams.  For example, [here is one webpage describing how to skip forward in a LCG](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-skipping-in-a-linear-congruential-generator).

Answer (score 4):

## Clean up

I don't know why it had to be so long and to have so many temporary variables. So I shortened it to make sense out of it. Here's what I got.

```
static int RandomHashFunction(int input, int max)
{
    using (var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()) // Disposing things is a good habit
    {
        var ascii = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        var hashAsString = ascii.GetChars(
            sha1.ComputeHash(
                ascii.GetBytes(input.ToString())
            )
        );

        return Convert.ToInt32(
            Math.Abs(
                Math.IEEERemainder(hashAsString.GetHashCode(), max)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

## WAT?

It is still not obvious to me, what are you attempting to achieve. Could you provide:

1. a few samples of input and output.
2. declare a variable that you *think* works as a seed.
3. a reference to a particular algorithm you're trying to implement or at least are inspired by.
4. OR at least a mathematical formula that you think will give you the desired result.

To me, there are a lot of unnecessary steps and manipulations.

- `Convert.ToInt16` was used to return and `int` (which is `Int32`) -- this was losing some meaning units of the number...
- `Math.Abs`. Why bother with it if the `Math.IEEERemainder` already gives you a number.
- Relying on `String::GetHashCode` may also be a bad thing since

  > The behavior of GetHashCode is dependent on its implementation, which might change from one version of the common language runtime to another: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx)

All these things seem very excessive and result in a messy code IMO.

## Update 1

Updated the code to use symmetric `GetChars` and `GetBytes` based on the same encoding.

## Update 2

Frankly, I am not finding the updated question very explanatory. The signature of the original function does not declare meaningful parameters. So I had to guess what their meaning is.

I also don't understand why a regular `Random.Next*()` won't work for you. It's trivial!

```
static int RandomHashFunction1(int seed = 1, int max)
{
    var randomDouble = new Random(seed).NextDouble();
    return (int)Math.Round(randomDouble * max);
}
```

If you really want to stay away from `System.Random`, you can use `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` as you do in the original code, but **I don't see why it is necessary**.

```
static int RandomHashFunction2(int seed = 1)
{
    using (var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(sha1.ComputeHash(BitConverter.GetBytes(seed)), startIndex: 0);
}
```

Lastly, I don't see why do you need to use any string representation at all and go through unnecessary steps with `Math.*` which make your function computationally heavier.

Please consider accepting the answer as it does the job, OR carefully describe the acceptance criteria. Your problem statement is unclear!

## Update 3

Okay, you updated the question with the important info, which I quote here

> need to generate terrain so say we have a line that consists of dots with an X and a Y value. The X values start at 0 and can go to positive and negative infinity depending on the player position. Depending on the X I need a random Y. System.Random gives a random number and then another random number based on the previous one. If I would only move to the right I could keep on generating terrain based on the previous dot using random.Next () But if I wanted to go back I would need the previous number with you can't do with Random.Next().

This is the new version of the function that should meet your more precise problem definition.

```
static int ConsistentRandom(
    int maxRandomInt,
    int seedInGame = 1,
    int specificLocationInGame = 0
)
{
    var actualSeedForRandom = seedInGame + specificLocationInGame;
    var randomDouble = new Random(actualSeedForRandom).NextDouble();
    return (int)Math.Round(randomDouble * maxRandomInt);
}
```

Notice that `var actualSeedForRandom = seedInGame + specificLocationInGame;` may be implemented in many various ways, I just used the simplest formula that came to my mind.

Here's a test console app:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (var iteration = 1; iteration <= 2; iteration++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST ITERATION " + iteration);
        for (var seed = 0; seed < 2; seed++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SEED " + seed);
            for (var location = 0; location < 5; location++)
            {
                Console.Write(ConsistentRandom(10, seed, location));
                if (location != 4) Console.Write(" - ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And here's what it produces:

[image]

As you can see, as long as you know the `seedInGame`, you control the sequence of randoms. And if you know both the `seedInGame` and `specificLocationInGame`, you can easily get the specific value of random for this combination.

In other words, your Game should pick a new `seedInGame` on every new map it's trying to generate. The value of `specificLocationInGame` will let you "teleport" anywhere within this particular map.

## Update 4 - To Address Concerns About Randomness

Here's the exact code I used to generate some consistent but random number sequence. The resulting sequence can be [downloaded from here](https://ufile.io/8oamu).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"C:\temp\generatedRandom.txt";
    if (File.Exists(path))
        File.Delete(path);
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
    using (var textWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        var seed = 42;
        for (var location = 0; location < 3 * 3000 * 3000; location++)
        {
            var randomByte = ConsistentRandom(Int64.MaxValue, seed, location);
            textWriter.Write(randomByte);
            Console.WriteLine(randomByte);
        }
    }
}

static Int64 ConsistentRandom(
    Int64 maxRandomInt,
    int seedInGame = 1,
    int specificLocationInGame = 0
)
{
    var actualSeedForRandom = seedInGame + specificLocationInGame;
    var randomDouble = new Random(actualSeedForRandom).NextDouble();
    return (Int64)Math.Round(randomDouble * maxRandomInt);
}
```

I then used [ent - pseudorandom number sequence test](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) for checking how well the solution performs in terms of randomness.

[image]

I think, only the author can judge how far or how close this result is located from the desired one.

## Update 5 - Visualizing the Solution (or How I Screwed Up)

Okay, I built a [little tool to visualize the generated "random" sequence](http://soloydenko.com/randvizer/) via the proposed algorithm (since I didn't find one online). The following picture demonstrates "little regularities" in the sequence... Well, the "random" sequence has very distinguishable regularities, so the proposed approach does not guarantee good results. I think, it's valid to suppose that approach in fact guarantees *bad results*. :(

@Wagacca, you were right in our conversation under my answer!

[image]

Comment: Alright I improved it. I hope it's clear now what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Wagacca please see the Update 2

Comment: Alright.  I need to generate terrain so say we have a line that consists of dots with an X and a Y value. The X values start at 0 and can go to positive and negative infinity depending on the player position. Depending on the X I need a random Y. System.Random gives a random number and then another random number based on the previous one. If I would only move to the right I could keep on generating terrain based on the previous dot using random.Next () But if I wanted to go back I would need the previous number with you can't do with Random.Next(). That's why I need a hashing function.

Comment: @Wagacca now it makes WAY MORE SENSE!

Comment: @Wagacca I have a solution in mind. Will update the answer within the next 2-6 hours...

Comment: @Wagacca Update 3 should do it...

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong, but are you saying that I can use the standard Random class and generate random numbers by seeding the Random class? So don't use Random.next at all, just seed it again for each x value?

Comment: @Wagacca if you have two different instances of the same System.Random class, and if they both were created with the same seed, these two objects will provide same sequences of random numbers. So, if you call `.NextRandom()` three times on instance1 and get `0.31`, `0.63`, `0.19`, then you know what three first call on instance one will return you. I used this fact and created a compound seed that uses two different numbers summed up to. Each of these numbers now represents a "dimension" if you will... Does it make sense?

Comment: `So don't use Random.next at all, just seed it again for each x value?` Well, use still use the `next`, but only once per instance of a Random class. The correctness of the seed becomes important. I think you got the idea right.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your code but I was warned of this. Is this relevant in your code?:

Can’t I just use random number generators with different seed values?

No! This is a very common misconception about RNGs. The fact is that while the different numbers in the same sequence are random in relation to each other, the same indexed numbers from different sequences are not random in relation to each other, even if it may look like it at first glance.

from:https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/01/07/a-primer-on-repeatable-random-numbers/

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. However, If you generate your `seedInGame` for every new game randomly, that thing you mentioned is not the issue anymore. ;)

Comment: Otherwise, you may go superstrict about this "correctness" of randomness. Your original hashing code does not solve the problem you have at all. And I don't see any obvious way to solve the problem, other than **storing the entire generated sequence**, which is **computationally cheap, but memory expensive**.

Comment: From what I understood if you compare the first random number generated by C# using the Random Class and to the following:
y = Random(seed0), y = Random(seed +1) , y = Random(seed +n). The result will be completely unusable. Here's an image generated by numbers created by getting the first number in of each of 65536 sequences created from the seeds 0 to 65535 https://blogs.unity3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/SubsequentSeedsNoise.png

Comment: The middle one is the one using the first number generated by a seed over and over again and increasing the seed by one

Comment: I have already responded to that. Yes, I get that every given picture starts having a pattern. The same may or may not be applicable if you select a random number from a _randomly chosen (on each pick) sequence_. I don't have a graphic representation to prove/disprove/quantify viability of that approach. The alternative was also mentioned above. If you want "true randomness" you need to stick to an instance of System.Random class, and keep using `next*()`. Since `previous*()` does not exist, I'm pretty sure the only way will be to store the generated elements of the sequence.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if the issue you mentioned is specific to `System.Random`. If so, you indeed may simply replace the random value provider from `System.Random` to `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider`and the results may be very different -- I don't know.

Comment: @Wagacca I added one more update to my proposed solution, so that we don't have to argue about something that can be measured.  If you know the tool I can use to generate these nice 2D images that help understand patterns in random data, I can use it against the data file I have and attach it to the post.